# How do i make Wordpress Auto Republish old post to make them look new on search results

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Please I need to delete and repost my old posts on WordPress so that they can be reindexed by search engines like new content. I don't want to manually do it. Please can someone help with an idea of how to?

Comment: It seems to me if google did not index them, it is better to resubmit your sitemap.xml in search engines instead of again creating posts, by deleting the posts it is possible to make several 404 errors. Also, if you cannot see your website in SERP, you may need to check what you did in off-page SEO.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The question was not really clear. The thing is that posts are already indexed, but I have seen a situation whereby whenever I search for an old Item on the internet, a particular site comes up with those old posts but then they are displayed by browsers as 10 hours ago 1 day ago and so on. It is hard to explain but I hope you try to understan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you update your posts' post_date values. There are plugins for the purpose.

But be careful. Search engines like Google are really good at detecting attempts to play games with them to boost search rankings. People have been playing those games since Yahoo ruled the search-engine world. If they detect such things on a site they down-rank it or even stop showing it altogether. Simply updating dates without changing content may trigger a game-playing filter. You don't want that.

Ask yourself the question, "how do I make my site more useful to people who search for it?" New and updated content is a good way to do that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice I think your way is better.